# C# loop through the registry searching for keys containing certain text

Tags: c#, search, loops, registry, registrykey

Is it possible to go through the registry and copy the names of all keys found with a certain text?

For example, say I had keys under SOFTWARE of item1, item2, item fred, item34 etc. Am I able to do a search under software for all keys containing the word item and save their name to a variable, where I can later display these items on a winform of detected software.

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey pathKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE");
```

Not that I want someone to code it for me, rather give me a starting place for the loop.

Comment: On a related note.  If you actually want to know *how* to do this, I suggest you post some code with regards to what you've tried or at least let us know where, exactly, you are stuck.

Comment: There is no code at the moment other than the registry key to start the search. The part I am confused about is how to loop through the registry, how can I define the parameters of the loop using the registry?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to search for specific value in Registry keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295257/how-to-search-for-specific-value-in-registry-keys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at this StackOverFlow Link it appears that the individual has come up with a way to look for "VisualStudio" hope this helps

[How to Query Registry for a Specific Key(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295257/how-to-search-for-specific-value-in-registry-keys)

Comment: Good call, although not exact, the question you found is close enough to be a duplicate.

Comment: It should be close enough to help him get started since the OP stated that there is not code at the moment I am still waiting to hear back from the OP to see if the link could help him or not...

Comment: Thanks DJ Kraze, I'll take a look and see how I go :P Looks slightly complicated but could be a nice learning curve, I'll edit my main post as I go :P

Comment: The first answer points him at MSDN, and the page for [GetSubKeyNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.getsubkeynames.aspx) has a code sample.  The only point of confusion may be understanding what subkeys are and their relationships, but that's in the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry#Keys_and_values) about the windows registry.

Comment: I totally agree.. but I am glad that he has done better than most on here who don't look at examples that we point them too.. he took the time to probably read it and test or try something. so +1 will definitely go to the OP

Comment: cheeseman don't let it throw you off just debug and check values as you step into the code that you utilize.. that's another good way of upping your coding skills when you learn something that you never anticipated yourself to learn.. I think you will do well..

Comment: Got there in the end, excellent learning experience, thanks :)