# Search for specific word in registry and delete keys

Tags: c#, search, registry

I'm currently working on a project where i need to find all occurrences of the word "Skyprint" in the registry and then delete them.

I'm doing this to remove all traces of a failed printer-installation.

I've tried looking up some ways of doing it, but it appears i can't find a way to do it :(

Also, i'm new to programming - be nice :)

Comment: Have a look here, especially the answer with `RegistryKey`class: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295257/how-to-search-for-specific-value-in-registry-keys

Answer (score 0):

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531151/how-to-delete-a-registry-value-in-c-sharp) by Jon Skeet

Also check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk8b3th2.aspx) and this [tutorial](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2016/02/registry-deletesubkeytree.html).

Comment: This lets me delete the keys that i already know the locations of.. I need to find all items in the registry that has the word "skyprint" and delete them..

Comment: Do u try with this one:  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/339bd6db-a558-4f3a-9054-a46d0e80edd0/how-to-find-all-specific-registry-key-and-delete-them-using-c?forum=csharpgenera

Comment: I've looked at this already. I'm afraid i can't figure out what to do with this code :(
It would be really great if someone could point out the obvious, like show where to type in the word i want to search for .. like " TYPE YOUR SEARCH HERE " or somthing like that